# OpenSSL encryption/decryption

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I'm currently trying to make a simple program that encrypts a binary file (.zip) saves it in another format (.cry) and then decrypts the .cry file back to it's original state.

I'm getting no errors but when i try to open the decrypted .zip file i get an error from the archiving program.

Note: the original .zip file just contains a small .txt file with 3 words written.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>


int main(){
const EVP_CIPHER* pCipher = EVP_aes_128_ecb();
EVP_CIPHER_CTX* pCtx = new EVP_CIPHER_CTX;
//int nBl = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size( pCtx );
FILE *fin;
FILE *fout;
FILE *fdecr;
long fin_size,fout_size,fdecr_size;
unsigned char *fin_buf;
unsigned char *fout_buf;
unsigned char *fdecr_buf;

size_t rezultat;


fin = fopen("arhiva.zip", "rb");
fout = fopen("arhiva.zip.cry","wb");
fdecr= fopen("decript.zip","wb");
if (fin==NULL)
    {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}
if (fout==NULL)
    {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}
if (fdecr==NULL)
    {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}


fseek (fin , 0 , SEEK_END);
fin_size = ftell (fin);
fout_size=fin_size;
fdecr_size=fin_size;
rewind (fin);
fin_buf = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)*fin_size);

fdecr_buf= (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)*fin_size);
if (fin_buf == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}
//if (fout_buf == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}
if (fdecr_buf == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

//copiere fisier in buffer
rezultat = fread (fin_buf,1,fin_size,fin);
if (rezultat != fin_size) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}



      //pregatire criptare
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init( pCtx );

unsigned char pKey[192];
unsigned char pIV[192];
RAND_bytes(pKey,24);
RAND_bytes(pIV,24);

EVP_EncryptInit_ex( pCtx, pCipher, NULL, pKey, pIV);
EVP_DecryptInit_ex( pCtx, pCipher, NULL, pKey, pIV);

      //cript

int nOutLen = 0;
int nTmpOutLen = 0;

fout_buf = (unsigned char*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned char)*fout_size);
memset( fout_buf, 0, fout_size);

EVP_EncryptUpdate( pCtx,fout_buf,&nTmpOutLen,fin_buf,fin_size );
nOutLen += nTmpOutLen;
EVP_EncryptFinal( pCtx,fout_buf + nTmpOutLen,&nTmpOutLen );
fwrite(fout_buf, 1, fout_size, fout);

//decript
nOutLen = 0;
nTmpOutLen = 0;
memset( fdecr_buf, 0, fdecr_size);

EVP_DecryptUpdate(pCtx,fdecr_buf,&nTmpOutLen,fout_buf,fout_size );
nOutLen += nTmpOutLen;
EVP_DecryptFinal( pCtx,fdecr_buf + nTmpOutLen,&nTmpOutLen );
fwrite(fdecr_buf, 1, fdecr_size, fdecr);


fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
fclose(fdecr);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(pCtx);


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Create separate functions right from the start, that makes it much easier to debug your code. Include log statements so you can see what you are doing. Do debug your code before asking on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nOutLen` is increased with `nTmpOutLen` for the update part, but not for the finalization part.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you don't write the whole encryption/decryption output to the file. Write there nOutLen, not fdecr_size.
You are using ECB mode, so your encrypted data will be padded to 16-byte boundary.
Also I would recommend to use CBC mode.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems:

- The code assumes that the encrypted file will be the same size as the original file.  This is generally not the case, especially not with block ciphers such as AES-128 in ECB mode which you are using. In fact, you are overflowing `fout_buf` in the call to `EVP_EncryptFinal()`.
- You need to correctly calculate `nOutLen` across the EVP operations (including `*Final`) and handle that many bytes of encrypted or decrypted output. For instance, you only write `fout_size` bytes of encrypted data to the `.cry` file, which is less than what OpenSSL wrote to the buffer, which in turn leads to a corrupted last block after decryption and thus to the archiver errors.
- You use the same context `pCtx` interleaved for both encryption and decryption. You should use separate context structures for encryption and for decryption.
- You reserve 192 bytes for both `pKey` and `pIV`, proceed to fill 24 bytes each with random data, but only 16 bytes of the key gets used by OpenSSL in the end (AES-128), and none of the IV (ECB mode uses no IV).